# Multiple Cmakelist.txt

Tags: ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Cmakelist.txt that looks as follows in my project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(softmanbot)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization)
catkin_package()

include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(softmanbot_supervisor_node
    common/genericSupervisor.cpp common/genericSupervisor.hpp common/genericLogic.hpp
    supervisor/specificSupervisor.cpp supervisor/specificSupervisor.hpp
    )

add_executable(softmanbot_genericDeformationControl_node 
    common/genericDeformationControl.cpp common/genericDeformationControl.hpp common/genericLogic.hpp   
    deformationControl/specificDeformationControl.cpp deformationControl/specificDeformationControl.hpp
    )

add_executable(softmanbot_genericSkilledWorkcell_node
    common/genericSkilledWorkcell.cpp common/genericSkilledWorkcell.hpp common/genericLogic.hpp
    skilledWorkcell/specificSkilledWorkcell.cpp skilledWorkcell/specificSkilledWorkcell.hpp 
    )

add_executable(softmanbot_genericPerception_node
    common/genericPerception.cpp common/genericPerception.hpp common/genericLogic.hpp
    perception/specificPerception.cpp perception/specificPerception.hpp
    )


target_link_libraries(softmanbot_supervisor_node
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(softmanbot_genericDeformationControl_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)


target_include_directories(softmanbot_genericSkilledWorkcell_node PUBLIC ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(softmanbot_genericSkilledWorkcell_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)


target_link_libraries(softmanbot_genericPerception_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Is this possible to split it in several Cmakelists.txt? I have project-requirement reasons to do this.
I'd like to have one by node, which have sources in different folders.
Anyone knows how to make so the main project Cmakelists act as a "orchestra chief" that just calls the other one so I can put specific includes in each nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388950/multiple-cmakelist.txt/) by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2021-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has always been the [`include()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) in CMake, so you can just do:

```
include(buildLibA.txt)
include(LibB/CMakeLists.txt)
```

Or, for the second case, [`add_subdirectory()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) would be better:

```
include(buildLibA.txt)
add_subdirectory(LibB)
```

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2021-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2021-10-20**:
Will try that and accept answer if that works. Would also update files in a separate answer so someone with same problem can solve in the future

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer from @KenYN works.
CMakelist.txt now looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(testBenchMichelin)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

include(deformationControl/deformationControlCMake.txt)
include(supervisor/supervisorCMake.txt)
include(skilledWorkcell/skilledWorkcellCMake.txt)
include(perception/perceptionCMake.txt)
```

Each specific file hold relevant information. Doesn't looks like there are conflict with same library inclusions in several nodes.

---

Originally posted by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) with karma: 71 on 2021-10-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2021-10-28**:
Be weary if you include some message generations. I had to split up things in cmake1.txt and cmake2.txt to ensure calling catkin_package once after message generations. Haven't tried multiple messages defined on several files yet.